# NullPointerException uploading file (struts2 + hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, websphere

I'm getting a null pointer exception and can't seem to resolve it.. I'm using Struts2 and hibernate.

In my ProfileAction:

```
public String profilePhoto() {
    String pathToSaveInDB = null;
    String uploadFolder = null;
    String filePath = null;

    try {
        uploadFolder = "profile_pic";
        filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + uploadFolder;
        System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);

        System.out.println(this.userImageFileName);
        System.out.println(this.userImage);

        pathToSaveInDB = uploadFolder + "/" + this.userImageFileName;

        FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);

        System.out.println("user id: " + getId());
        System.out.println("photo path: " + pathToSaveInDB);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    profileDAO.updateProfilePhoto(Long.parseLong("1"), "test"); <==== just testing
    return SUCCESS;

}
```

My ProfileDAOImpl:

```
@Override
public void updateProfilePhoto(Long id, String path) {

    String SQL_QUERY = "update Profile set ProfilePhotoPath = :path" +
        " where UserId = :id";
    try {
        System.out.println(SQL_QUERY);
        Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
query.setParameter("id", id);
query.setParameter("path", path);

        int result = query.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

My form:

```
<s:form action="profilePic" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="userImage">Profile Avatar:</label> <br />
            <s:file name="userImage" label="User Image" />
            <s:set name="userId" value="#session.User.id"/>
            <s:hidden name="id" value="%{#userId}" />
            <s:submit value="Upload" />
        </s:form>
```

The error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.fotoalbum.dao.ProfileDAOImpl.updateProfilePhoto(ProfileDAOImpl.java:95)
com.fotoalbum.web.ProfileAction.profilePhoto(ProfileAction.java:89)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:320)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:320)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

The error is specifically stating that `profileDAO.updateProfilePhoto(Long.parseLong("1"), "test");` in my ProfileAction and `transaction.rollback();` in my ProfileDAOImpl is the cause.. Thanks in advance for any help :)

If you need me to post more of my codes, do let me know. Cheers~

Comment: what is at line 95 of `com.fotoalbum.dao.ProfileDAOImpl` class?Also, in `updateProfilePhoto()` , where are you creating the session and transaction objects

Answer (score 0):

I think your transaction is null. Where do you start the transaction?

Comment: I'm still pretty new with struts2 and hibernate concept. I'm guessing the answer to your question is ProfileDAOImpl?

Comment: Oh and I'm using Hibernate Full Plugin. That might explain the code a bit? The thing that I can't understand is that I'm using almost the exact code for updating my user profile and it works however it doesn't work in this case. I'm guessing it is my file upload form page that is the cause of the error.. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think your interceptors are not configured well

I got this kind of issue and cleared through following code .....

Action Method :

```
public String execute() {

    try {
        String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);

        FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addActionError(e.getMessage());

        return INPUT;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

struts.xml :

```
        <action name="userImage">
        class="FileUploadAction">

        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">

        <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>

        <param name="allowedTypes">

        image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg

        </param>

        </interceptor-ref>

        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>

        <result name="success">SuccessUserImage.jsp</result>

        <result name="input">UserImage.jsp</result>
```